# How to resolve Class is not a constructor error in Typescript Mocha Testing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I've got the following class:

```
import http, { RequestListener } from 'http';
import { Application } from './application';

export class WebServer {

  private httpServer: http.Server;
  private requestListener: RequestListener;

  public async start(application: Application, port: number) {
    this.requestListener = application.getRequestListener();
    this.httpServer = http.createServer(this.requestListener);
    await this.httpServer.listen(port);
  }

  public async stop() {
    await this.httpServer.close();
  }

  public getHttpServer(): http.Server {
    return this.httpServer;
  }

  public getRequestListener(): RequestListener {
    return this.requestListener;
  }
}
```

I have the following simple test case:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';
import { Application } from './../infrastructure';
import { WebServer } from './../infrastructure';

describe('WebServer Tests', () => {
    const webServer = new WebServer();
    const webServerProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(webServer)
    it('Checking WebServer Initialization', () => {
        expect(webServerProto).to.not.be.null;
        expect(webServerProto.httpServer).to.not.be.null;
        expect(webServerProto.requestListener).to.not.be.null;
    });
```

I'm getting an import error when I run the test. Namely, I get the following:

```
TypeError:"uncaughtException": WebServer is not a constructor
```

That's leading me to believe something's wrong with my imports in my test file. For reference this is my start script and my test script:

```
"start": "node --inspect=5858 -r ts-node/register ./src/index.ts"
    "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_FILES=true mocha --exit --require ts-node/register --watch-extensions ts --colors ./src/test/*-tests.ts",
```

Would anyone know what I need to do with my test environment to be able to access the WebServer class? npm start works just fine. I'm getting the constructor error when I run npm test. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you have some circular dependencies, eg.  try `console.log(WebServer)` before calling new..

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to the class WebServer

```
import http, { RequestListener } from 'http';
import { Application } from './application';

export class WebServer {

  constructor(){}
  private httpServer: http.Server;
  private requestListener: RequestListener;

  public async start(application: Application, port: number) {
    this.requestListener = application.getRequestListener();
    this.httpServer = http.createServer(this.requestListener);
    await this.httpServer.listen(port);
  }

  public async stop() {
    await this.httpServer.close();
  }

  public getHttpServer(): http.Server {
    return this.httpServer;
  }

  public getRequestListener(): RequestListener {
    return this.requestListener;
  }
}
```

Also a side note, your import paths look odd.

I would have expected

```
import { WebServer } from './../infrastructure/WebServer';
import { Application } from './../infrastructure/Application';
```